# Python Scapy and read a pcap in reverse mode

Tags: python, networking, pcap, packet-capture, scapy

I'm reading a *pcap* file using the `rdpcap` function:

```
s = rdpcap(pcap)
```

I'd like to know how to reverse `s`: it should be a list, but I tried with:

```
rev_s = s.reverse()
```

and it doesn't work: it gives me the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: It gives me `<type 'instance'>`.
I found a syntax error, but now, it gives me this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "myscript.py", line 100, in myfunction
        for pkt in s.reverse():
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I know that `s` is not `None`.

Comment: `s = None` hence the TypeError you're getting. If `s` was a string you could use `.reverse()` or `[::-1]` to step it backwards. I'd recommend loading up a file that contains data, then doing a `dir(var_name)` on it to see what functions it supports.

Comment: As what you're trying to achieve works just fine (cf. my answer below), you have other mistakes in your code. If you do not mange to resolve them by yourself, you can show more code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this works:

```
>>> a = rdpcap("test.pcap")
>>> b = a.reverse()
>>> c = a[::-1]
```

(you can also use the slice notation to create a reversed copy of the list)